# add a line to file that contains quotes and variable using bash

Tags: bash, quoting, grub, variable

I want to add this line to /etc/grub.d/00_header

> set superusers="ubuntu"

where ubuntu is the result of $USER.
I've tried this:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "set superusers='"${USER}"'" >> /etc/grub.d/00_header'
```

but it added the line without quotes:

> set superusers=ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the double quotes you want preserved as literal:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "set superusers=\"${USER}\""'
```

Comment: If I do this command `sudo bash -c 'echo "set superusers=\"${USER}\"" >> /etc/grub.d/00_header'` the result of $USER will be root, not the user ubuntu...

Comment: @LuffyWallis: That is because you are using `sudo bash -c` although that sort of falls into a new question of it's own.